# How to use Flutter Cupertino Icons?

Tags: dart, flutter, flutter-cupertino

I know that to use them you have to `import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';`and use it like this `Icon(CupertinoIcons.info);` but it's hard to pick needed icon.

Dear Flutter team, please make complete Cupertino icons reference somewhere. One [place](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/cupertino/CupertinoIcons-class.html#constants) has names without icons and [other](https://github.com/flutter/cupertino_icons) has icons without names.

**UPDATE:**

As Mariano noted and as shown in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51107237/614026) name mapping is not yet complete and we can use icons as follows:

```
 const IconData baseball = const IconData(0xf3dd,
          fontFamily: CupertinoIcons.iconFont,
          fontPackage: CupertinoIcons.iconFontPackage);
 Icon(baseball);
```

Where 0xf3dd is a code of an icon (f3dd) which you can find [here](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/flutter/cupertino_icons/master/map.png).

Answer (score 6):

> You answered your own question, the usage of the CupertinoIcons class is as you described.

You are right though, there is **no easy way** to find the name of the icon from the map image provided in the github repository, since they don't directly map the system icons described by Apple in their human interface guidelines: [Human interface guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/design/human-interface-guidelines/ios/icons-and-images/system-icons/)

You can go to the main flutter repository and open an issue about this subject [Flutter Github repo](https://github.com/flutter/flutter).
 You could even contribute the map yourself and help other developers that might be having the same issue.